# Kendo Grid 'change' Event not firing

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a separate component on a page that (conditionally) updates a Kendo UI Grid.  When the user clicks on a row...I want the change event to fire.  However, it currently is NOT firing.

Why isn't the change event firing?

**DOJO:**
I have created [the following DOJO](https://dojo.telerik.com/@robert.jordan@energytransfer.com/AJeHA) in-support of this question.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `change` event is related to selection. To make the event fire, enable selection.

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/selectable

Comment: Hahahaha.  Okay...that is just stupid!  Why in the WORLD would someone create a grid that doesn't select by-default?  THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean `change` event from datasource (not from the grid) ?